# Statement level reflection in java

Tags: java, reflection

I'm looking for a mechanism in java (maybe like `Reflection`) to access the statements in a program. for example i access the statements of a function, then walk throw the statement tree to have analysis on java programs.

In .Net Microsoft provides the [`Extended Reflection`](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/extendedreflection/). what is the alternative in java?

---

For C files, [`CIL`](http://kerneis.github.io/cil/) process the `.c` source files and allow us to access the statements and walk throw the tree (even changing and inserting codes) statically. if there is a tool that process the `.java` codes and does similar works, can solve my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible without access to the underlying source code.  Java source code is compiled to byte code which is ran by the JVM and I would suspect .class files would not retain information about the source code they are built from.  You could almost think of it like type erasure with generics, kind of the same concept.

Comment: Don't now if it suites your needs, but you can try Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()

Comment: @JoaoPereira That would give you the call stack, but would it reveal things like assignments? Does the OP care about them?

Comment: I don't think so. As stated elsewhere the source code is lost when compiled to bytecode. You can really see this, when debugging in eclipse, if you reach a method call that lives in a class which you only have the .class file for, eclipse will tell you that it can't debug because it doesn't know the exact statements.

Comment: @Cruncher I don't know the answer and this is all speculation but how would something like findBugs work?  Maybe it is possible?

Comment: @Cruncher Guess its looking at byte code also.  I really think the OP needs the source code.

Comment: @KevinBowersox the point is, the mapping from source code to byte code is Many to One. There are a lot of source codes that will get compiled to the exact same byte code. And the same source code is not guaranteed to generate the same byte code with every compiler. You can GUESS the statements, but you certainly can't know them.

Comment: @Cruncher Makes sense, I agree with your initial statements just trying to further analyze and discuss this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aim to analyze Java code via a Java application you will need a copy of the source code.  `.java` files are essentially text files, so with the source code in hand your program could read the files similar to reading any text file.

There are several tools such as PMD and Clover that will perform this analysis for you.  It may save time and resources to use an established tool.  Although Clover is no longer a free tool it provides extensive metrics on code complexity.  I believe PMD may provide similar metrics.

Comment: Given the edit that made right before this post, it appears he actually has the source code

Comment: I guess the question looms, "What exactly does the OP want to analyze?"

Comment: if a tool exists for this work, its reinventing the wheel. but if not its the only option.

Comment: @mrdabd I would highly recommend an existing tool.  What do you want to know about the code?